# Attaching a flame system to an object

Tags: game-engine, particles

I have downloaded a BGE fire emitter file online. Now I would like to know if I could use this emitter to attach it to a vehicle and trigger the animation when the vehicle is collided. Is it possible?

Comment: You should post a snippet of your code here , so that others could review what have you been trying up to this point, most people are reluctant to help when it sounds like "Help me with my homework"

Answer (score 1):

When your (not specified yet) emitter consists of an object that adds other objects from it's own position, you can parent it to another object. This way the newly added objects will be added at the current position of the emitter.

This is useful on engine trails, smoke, fire.